# How can sem_open() accept different argument sizes if function overloading isn't supported in C?

Tags: c, linux, operator-overloading, semaphore, variadic-functions

While learning about shared process semaphores, I noticed that sem_open() features two function prototypes: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html

```
sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag);
sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode, unsigned int value);
```

How is this possible if function overloading isn't supported by C?

Comment: It's a variadic function, like `printf()`

Comment: You may want to read this: [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)

Comment: Hmm.. what's the difference between variadic functions and function overloading?

Comment: @Izzo: C does not have function overloading. That is a feature specific to C++ (and other languages).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Updated my question. Maybe my understanding of function overloading is incorrect, but a function that can take different argument sets seems like it's function overloading.

Comment: @Izzo: Variadic functions use an elipsis `...` in the function declaration in C and C++, which allows for an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type. In constrast, function overloading in C++ allows the same function name to have several specific signatures. However, in C++, things can [get more complicated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) when using default arguments, templates and template deductions.

Comment: @Izzo: You are right that there are similarities between variadic functions and function overloading. However, in C++, those are two distinct language features, and, in constrast to C, variadic functions are not used much in C++. In C++, they are mainly supported for compatibility with C. C++ uses more modern features such as function overloading, default arguments, templates, template deductions and [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not have overloading. What it *does* have is variadic functions.

**Overloaded functions** are functions that have multiple forms of the function with different arguments for each one.

**Variadic functions** are functions in C that can take a variable number of arguments. This is indicated with an ellipses (...), and while this is not apparent in the man page, if you look at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/semaphore.h.html#40) for sem_open() you can see it:

```
/* Open a named semaphore NAME with open flags OFLAG.  */
extern sem_t *sem_open (const char *__name, int __oflag, ...) __THROW;
```

As you can see, after __name and __oflag, the ellipses indicates that *technically* any number of arguments can be entered. But what the man page indicates is what variables sem_open() can actually handle. So really, this isn't two functions with different logic, but a single function that can handle  two different sets of arguments.

If you'd like to know more, there is [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/modern-c-variadic-functions-how-shoot-yourself-foot-avoid-zinin/) interesting article that covers some of the history behind variadic functions.

Answer (score 1):

The key is found in the manpage (which you linked):

> If `O_CREAT` is specified in `oflag`, then two additional arguments must be supplied.

That's exactly the way variadic functions work in C.  A variadic function has a fixed number of parameters, each with a well-defined type, and then a `...`, which can be any number of arguments of any type, with the proviso that the called function has to be able to figure out the type of each argument in order to reference it. `printf` is indeed the clearest example: the format string includes enough information for `printf` to know exactly how many and what type of arguments to expect.

Note that guessing is not permitted. If the function asks for an argument which wasn't provided or asks for a different type than the provided argument, it doesn't get a friendly error indication or a second chance. The result is Undefined Behaviour: anything can happen, including abrupt termination or a nonsensical result. Or a result which seems to make sense but has no basis in reality.

Like `open`, `sem_open` uses this to allow arguments which are only needed in certain well-defined circumstances. If it is possible that the call will create a new semaphore (or file, in the case of `open`), it will request the additional arguments, assuming that they are of the types specified in the documentation.

The caller is responsible for ensuring that the call is correct. Note that since variadic arguments do not have a declared type, the compiler cannot insert type conversions. So if the function is expecting a `double`, it cannot be called with an `int`, which would normally be possible. Also, if a variadic argument is supposed to be `void*`, it must be `void*`, and not, for example, `0` (or `NULL`), because the automatic conversion from 0 to a null pointer can't be done.

However, the caller is allowed to provide too many arguments, or conversely the called function is not required to examine every argument supplied. (It can't skip over arguments, but it doesn't need to get to the end of the list.)

In retrospect, this may seem like a terrible language feature. But it seemed like a good idea at the time, and it's not going away now.